# Protocol with twisted pair for multiple switch control in a tree topology?

Tags: rs485, serial-bus

For an irrigation system, I'm interested in simple switches. My requirements:

1. Communication over copper wires, e.g. a twisted pair of cables
2. Nodes(switches) can be set in a tree topology, all sharing the same cable pair or splits of the same pair.
3. Single master controlling all nodes over the copper cables.
4. Nodes to be able to output HIGH/LOW
5. Latency accepted up to 20s

```
                 MASTER         <- master node controlling all nodes
                / \    \           
               /   \    \ 
               A   B  _  C      <- Tube split, node expected to provide HI/LO
              / \    \ \           controller by master
             A1  A2  B1 B2      <- leaves are actual water consumers, outputs HI/LO
            /  \
           A1a A1b   ... etc'
```

Every node in the system symbolizes a water valve, leaves are end consumers (where water comes out), non-leaf nodes are simply splits in the water tube but basically fulfill the same function, which is an output of HIGH/LOW controller by the master node.

I have already looked into the following technologies but they don't seem to suit me:

1. RS485 - No support for tree topology
2. Fieldbus - Prohibitively expensive, functionality is overkill for my needs, which are just switches, no sensors required.

Are there other technologies that may fulfill the requirements above?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Why the need for a tree topology? This can be done in code. RS485 can be full duplex, but only one node at a time can be master.

Comment: Thanks! Tree topology because that reflects the physical topology of watering a terraced farm and because I'd like the wire to go along with the pipes, otherwise impossible.

Answer (score 0):

you can run RS485 in a tree topology so long as the data rate is slow enough that reflections do not cause problems.

the leaf nodes will need to unterminated else they'll eat all your signal you'll get negative reflections from all the branching points and positive refelctions from the leaves so you'll have to signal slow enough that the ripples cased by these reflections have time to subside

somethig less than one hundredth of lightspeed divided by network width is probably a good figure to aim below

So if the network is 300 metres across stay under 10000 baud: after 60 bounces the reflections will be very weak

Comment: That would be ideal. Do you have a link to some kind of documentation of this possibility? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your wiring length you could have a look at LIN. You don't need to implement the full protocol, as you can use LIN transceivers with an ordinary UART and any protocol.

If wiring length is too long you can try running it at slower speeds (eg. 9600 or 4800 or even lower, if the transceiver permits) or perhaps by designing a repeater module with two transceivers.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the idea of an RS485 repeater to provide an extension port from each  node (A, B, C etc.) like this: -

[image]

Original picture from [Dual Isolated Half-Duplex RS-485 Repeater by Texas Instruments](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidu590/tidu590.pdf?ts=1592122878992&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) and they say it is a verified design.

What I've added is in red so the repeater becomes a node with \$\color{red}{\text{LOCAL DATA USAGE}}\$ and an extension port for teeing off without disrupting the impedances of the data lines. In effect, each node becomes a 1:2 extender.

The above design uses isolating RS485 interfaces to prevent ground loops between slaves and between slaves and master. You don't need to use isolating transceivers providing that you are careful how you route power or, if power to each node is isolated already.

Given also that your system appears to be used outside (an irrigation system) and therefore open to the elements, it's probably a good idea to use TVS diodes at each port to prevent damage from indirect lightning strikes. Don't skimp on this.